# Jplayer and wordpress 3.6.x

Tags: wordpress, jplayer

I am embedding my Jplayer code into my website however there is already jquery within the wordpress installation but when I copy my code across the player is broken as it shows no the volume icon with the x over it. When I include an external jquery script it breaks the entrie site but the player works. Is there any better way for me to include jPlayer into my wordpress site?

Comment: I can't unfortunately the code is still hidden by the site owners. But its basic code and the player works once not in wordpress and including the external jquery file.

Comment: Look in the JavaScript error console what exactly breaks when you use the existing jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The jPlayer script enqueueing *has to play* by WordPress rules. The easiest (and maybe only) way is with a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). There are lot of developers, mainly Theme developers, that ignore that [**we don't dequeue the bundled jQuery version**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45440) and load any version from some CDN (at least, we don't do it without knowing exactly what we're doing).

Here's a rough test, the shortcode callback function has to be polished a lot.

```
public function plugin_setup() // hooked into plugins_loaded 
{
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
    add_shortcode( 'jplayer', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
}

public function enqueue()
{
    wp_register_script(
        'sj-jplayer', 
        $this->plugin_url . 'js/jquery.jplayer.min.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), // <------- Dependencies
        false,
        true
    );
    wp_register_style( 'sj-skin', $this->plugin_url . 'skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sj-jplayer' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sj-skin' );
}

public function shortcode( $atts, $content )
{
    ob_start();
    require_once('html-shortcode.php');
    $var = ob_get_clean();
    return $var;
}
```

The file `html-shortcode` is basically [this demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/) code adapted like:

```
<?php
/*
 * Prints the shortcode
 */
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) // <------ WP noConflict 
    {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({});
    });
</script>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```

I tested this jPlayer shortcode inside another that does a [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), and it worked on the iPad.

Comment: What I actually did was put the player in an iframe. Its not clean but it worked